# Initialization and filling database

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-data, derby, spring-boot

Today I have started to work with Spring Boot and I want to create Restfull services with Embedded Derby (Tomcat embedded done). How can I to manage of the autoconfigured DB and how to fill the DB ?

Comment: Excellent tutorial:  https://javabrains.io/courses/spring_core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [`EmbeddedDatabase`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/embedded/EmbeddedDatabase.html) (which is a subinterface of `DataSource`), as your `dataSource` bean. You can use [`EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/embedded/EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder.html) as a convenience class to help build the bean. You can use the builder to add your sql script, as well as set the [`EmbeddedDatabaseType`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/embedded/EmbeddedDatabaseType.html) Something like

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public EmbdeddedDataBase dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDataBaseBuilder()
                   .addScripts("...", "...")
                   .setType(EmbeddedDataBaseType.DERBY).
                   .build();
    }
}
```

`EmbeddedBataBase` and other mentioned classes are in the spring jdbc jar. Also make sure you have your derby jar.

Answer (score -1):

I have the following code so, it is bad (I mean the main class- configuration):

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class Application {

private static final String DRIVER = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
public static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:derby:db;create=true";


public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName(DRIVER);
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);

    connection.createStatement().execute("create table users(id integer, name varchar(20), surname varchar(20))");

    connection.createStatement().execute("insert into users values " + 
                                        "(1, 'aaaaaaaa', 'werwer'), " + 
                                        "(2, 'aaaa', 'werdfdfdfwer'), " + 
                                        "(3, 'aa', 'dfdfwerwer')");

    System.out.println("channels table created and recordes successfully inserted...");





    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

    String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    Arrays.sort(beanNames);
    for (String beanName : beanNames) {
        System.out.println(beanName);
    }
}

}
```